# AJAX call doesn't execute PHP function

Tags: php, ajax

I have made an AJAX call:

```
<div>
  <form id= "voting"  method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value='1'> 1
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value='2'> 2
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value='3'> 3
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value='4'> 4
    <input type="radio" name="rating" value='5'> 5
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function(){

    var value =[];

    $("#voting").click(function(){

      var value = $('input[name=rating]:checked').val();

      alert(value);

      $.ajax({
        asunc: true,
        type: "POST",
        url: "lib/index.php",
        data: { "vote" : value },
        error: function() {
          alert("Oops");
        },
        succes: function(data, textstatus, XMLHttpRequest, refresh ){
          alert("YEAH");
        }

      });
  });
});

</script>
```

When I click the radio button, it does give a pop-up with the value.
on index.php is an function which puts the data in the MySQL database:

```
public function voteinject(){
  if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
    error_log(print_r($_POST['vote'], true));

    $type_='W';
    $rating = $_POST['vote'];
  }

  $query  = "INSERT INTO vote (type, number) VALUES ('$type', $rating)";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
  return new JsonResponse($rating);
}
```

So the point is, that I can click on the radio buttons. Then there will appear a pop-up with the good result (no error's). The only thing missing is executing the vote inject() function.

If take the code out of the function still no result:

```
if (isset($_POST['vote'])) {
  error_log(print_r($_POST['vote'], true));


  $type_='W';
  $rating = $_POST['not'];


  $query  = "INSERT INTO vote (type, number) VALUES ('$type', $rating)";
  $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
  return new JsonResponse($rating);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Probably not the reason for your error but you have a typo in asunc/async

Comment: voteinject() is a function. Whereas you have not called this function in your index.php file ?

Comment: are you calling voteinject someway? ie voteinject(); dont forget to write correctly success instead of succes ;)

Comment: voteinject() is the function I made to insert the rating into the database.

I don't call the function on my index. I want it to be called when someone clicks on one of the radio buttons.

Comment: It is worth mentioning you have a dirty big SQL injection vulnerability in your PHP.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: What happens when you execute the php code directly (using postman or similar tools)?

Comment: I included the jQuery lib. There are no errors reported. 
I use it on a localhost server as a test.

Comment: The php code does work, if I call the function. But it seems the code is not executed when submitting via the radio button.

Comment: In order for people to help you, you need to make your question more specific to the exact problem. Do some debugging. Is it that your AJAX does not seem to be reaching the PHP page or that the database query is not executing correctly. Strip your code down to isolate each bit and discover which bits are working and which are not.

Comment: according to your js, $_POST[not] is not defined, is your column 'number' nullable?

Comment: It seems it is reaching the correct PHP file, just not executing the function.
the column 'number' is nullable yes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the snippet of PHP you have provided, the `voteinject()` function is declared but never called. To solve it add something like this...

```
voteinject();
```

Or move the code outside the function and just execute it as procedural PHP which is old fashioned but works.

Comment: I copied the index, renamed it (also changed the path in my Ajax). . Deleted everything, but the vote inject() function. I moved it outside the function. Still no effect on my database. 

I show you how it looks like now in my first post

Comment: Are you definitely connecting to the database?